Pressable markers in react-native-gifted-charts
I'm using react-native-gifted-charts to create a line chart in a React Native application, and I'm trying to add custom markers with press functionality. The chart and the custom marker renders properly, and the icons display as expected. However, tapping on the markers does not trigger the onPress handler.
const positiveMood = moodSnapshots.map((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.events) {
        return {
            value: (snapshot.avg_positive_mood * 100),
            label: new Date(snapshot.date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'short' }),
            showStrip: true,
            stripHeight: 200,
            stripStrokeDashArray: [5, 5],
            stripColor: 'grey',
            pointerEvents: 'auto',
            dataPointLabelComponent: () => eventMarkers(snapshot.events ? snapshot.events[0].event.icon_name : 'comma-box-outline'),
            dataPointLabelShiftY: - ((chartMaxValue - (snapshot.avg_positive_mood * 100)) * (chartHeight / chartMaxValue)),
            dataPointLabelShiftX: 5

        }
    }
    else {
        return {
            value: (snapshot.avg_positive_mood * 100),
            label: new Date(snapshot.date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'short' }),
        }
    }
});

const eventMarkers = (icon_name: string) => {
    return (
        <View
        style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            position: 'relative',
            zIndex: 100000
        }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPressIn={() => {console.log('pressed')}}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon_name as any} size={40} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

<LineChart
    height={chartHeight}
    data={positiveMood}
    data2={negativeMood}
    maxValue={chartMaxValue}
    color1="skyblue"
    color2="red"
    dataPointsColor1="skyblue"
    dataPointsColor2="red"
    textFontSize={13}
    curved
    stepValue= {10}
/>

I tried wrapping the entire dataPointLabelComponent in a TouchableOpacity.
Adding pointerEvents="auto".
Changing TouchableOpacity to Pressable.
Testing on both iOS and Android.
Expected Behavior:
hen I tap on a marker, the onPress handler inside TouchableOpacity should log the event name or perform any action I define.
Is there something about how react-native-gifted-charts renders dataPointLabelComponent that prevents touch events from working? How can I enable touch interactions for custom markers in the chart?
